# Firebase timestamp in php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Which method to use in php to generate firebase timestamp, which is equally to firebase.serverValue.timestamp?

I have tried using `time()`, apparently it's wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firebase.serverValue.timestamp
```

> public static final Map TIMESTAMP
>
> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers.
>   [Doc Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

As it reads in the documentation it's in millis. The actual definition of timestamp is in seconds but, anyway to get the actual timestamp in millis in PHP you have to

```
microtime();
```

Edit: 
to get millis from microseconds (returned by microtime()) you have to:

```
$timeparts = explode(" ",microtime());
$currenttime = bcadd(($timeparts[0]*1000),bcmul($timeparts[1],1000));
echo $currenttime;
```

Comment: microtime() generating `0.59891000 1476645407`, which is wrong format too.

Comment: @Basit yeah it's microtime sorry, but you have to translate it to milliseconds. I edited my answer

Comment: ok gonna try new method you wrote.., btw while I try this.. do we have to set UTC timezone?

Comment: @Basit If you look at the documentation for `microtime()` no. http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php the definition of timestamp is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1,1970 GMT) since GMT == UTC you're just set.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **Google SDK** for (Firebase / Firestore), you can use the following :

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp;

// ....

$stamp = new Timestamp(new DateTime());
```

Then store `$stamp` into database.. so you will get a field similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this thread is due for another update.  I am not sure if the other answers are still valid but the current recommended way to do it, according to google documentation, is as follows:

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue;

$timestamp = FieldValue::serverTimestamp()
```

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what the OP asks for. He needs the Timestamp object (within PHP) similar to what FieldValue's serverTimestamp saves within Firestore.